# Install ImageMagick on linux shared hosting

Tags: linux, hosting, shared-hosting, library, imagemagick

Is the installation of ImageMagick library possible for a non-root user in a shared hosting environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only possible if dependencies where also available already. Time for a new host...

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick does not require root to operate.  To install it in the 'standard' place, it will.

My suggestion is to find out if your packaging system allows alternate locations for installation.  If not, then you may have to compile from source and install it into a location you have permission to write to.  You may also have to do similar things with any package which uses ImageMagick.

Comment: uname -a reveals it is CentOS 5.3 so I tried to extract the official IM rpm and run the binary. This failed due to the libraries not being located in the correct dir. To make install from source the docs state that one must be root. Is this wrong then?

Comment: When compiling there is no "acceptable C compiler found in PATH". Is it possible to get around this by locating a compiler (binary) and not having to install it as normal (I am not root)?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to install a software on a restricted shared host using [this method](https://serverfault.com/questions/942701/how-to-install-a-binary-package-on-a-shared-hosting-for-example-aqbanking-or-m/942702#942702), you might be able to adapt it to ImageMagick. Feel free to post the full solution, if you succeed.